# Find the point where maximum intervals overlap for certain interval length

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, algorithm

I'm trying to maximize attendance to a event given a list of busy times for each person. The event can be scheduled anytime between a certain date and hours (Ex. March 1st to March 8th from 9-5) and that attendance is maximized.

So far I've tried using a sliding window approach, and a counting approach described here (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-point-where-maximum-intervals-overlap/) however I only managed to get the sliding window approach working with a time complexity of O(n^3) which unfortunately is not good enough for my use case. The counting approach does not work because I can find the maximum interval but not for a certain timeframe.

A worst case scenario use case would be ~500 people and a month timespan.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How is the list of busy times given? How many busy events are there?

Comment: List of busy times are in the form [{startdate, enddate}, ... etc] but I also have it in a form of 1 and 0's for given time periods where 1 is free and 0 is busy Ex [[1,0,1],[0,1,0]] where each one represents a person. And there can be as many busy events during a day as someone wants to schedule, so there is no limit

Comment: The busy/free periods are mentioned on a hourly basis?

Comment: Here's an example of the data I have [
  { start: 2021-03-03T05:00:00.000Z, end: 2021-03-03T07:00:00.000Z },
  { start: 2021-03-03T09:00:00.000Z, end: 2021-03-04T04:30:00.000Z }
]. This would represent a single person's calendar for one day. Currently I am doing it on a 5 minute intervals, however that interval is still too large to be computationally possible in reasonable timeframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using a Interval Tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree)

Comment: Sure, using this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/interval-tree-type, I initialized a tree. Then to this tree I take my data  { start: 2021-03-03T09:00:00.000Z, end: 2021-03-04T04:30:00.000Z } and add it to the tree using tree.insert(start.getTime(), end.getTime()). This stores the intervals in milliseconds. Using that, I then use a "sliding window" of sorts to each of the intervals in which I'd like my meeting to take place. This returns an array, which you can take the length from. The more objects, the more people are busy. So we take the min from that and compute best time.